# Application stops processing while Office Interop

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I had a problem where my application simply stoped doing anything at all when it reachs a certain Office Interop command, most recently it was a closing of Word.

```
worddoc.SaveAs("ExampleFile.doc", FileFormat:=Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
worddoc.Close()
wordap.Quit()
wordap = Nothing
```

In some cases, it was not reproducible at all, the application simply stoped to continue after reaching `worddoc.close()`. There was no Errormessage, no Windows telling me "... stopped working", nothing at all. When I stopped to application to check where it was stuck it always pointed me to the `worddoc.close` phrase no matter how many times I resumed and restopped the application (I always waited between 5 to 15 seconds before the next action) it the program cursor didn't moved at all.
This issue never appeared when I had a release configuration and did not intercept at any point with a breakpoint, especially it never appeared when distributing the application to the end-users.

Anyway I would like to know what causes this issue and how to fix it, because today I got a mail that told me it happens also in the end version, at least for some people.

Comment: after recompiling the project and sending him a new exe-file it worked again, but anyway there should be a reason for the application to stuck here

Comment: Probably not the suggestion you want to hear, but if you can solve the problem without OfficeInterop, it would make your project so much easier to maintain.

Comment: i know, but in this case its not possible (users want some features that are pretty Word specific

Comment: Understand. Not much more help, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16534943/2009) might have some tips on getting extra info you need to track down your issue.

Comment: So when you wrap this in a try-catch you don't get any exceptions? Here is a link to the code I use to [convert DOC to PDF](https://github.com/scstauf/SECExtract/blob/master/SECExtract/WordConverter.cs) and I've never had any problems with it, however it does require Word 2010 to run.

Comment: nope no exception at all, it just stuckes halfway from execution until i forcefully terminate the application. I worked with the Office-Interaction as well and never encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [SaveAs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Document class instead and specify the full path and document name passing as the first argument (not just a name).

Also I'd suggest releasing all underlying COM objects in the code. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

BTW Where do you run the code? Is it a windows service?

Do you have any Word add-ins running? If so, try to disable all of them.